# Ful Text Result Set

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

How can I explain the following result. Why the second query is resulting in more rows ? Intuitively when I restrict my criteria  by adding more words in query, the number of rows returned should be fewer.

```
mysql> select count(*)  from table1 WHERE MATCH (title, desc) AGAINST ('word');
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    76220 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.08 sec)

mysql> select count(*)  from table1 WHERE MATCH (title, desc) AGAINST  ('word blah');
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   120840 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.32 sec)
```

Comment: I have found  that in certain cases it ignores the second word.

Answer (score 0):

Found that its one OR the other. Which explains why the second has more rows.